# Problem printing CHAR array in C ++ language

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I try to print an array and I can not. Does anyone have any idea why ?

In the Main.cpp file there is of course a function call.

My code:

**Game.cpp:**

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game() {
    char example[] = "PASS";
}

bool Game::PrintArray() {
    cout << example[0] << endl;
    return true;
}
```

**Game.h:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

class Game {
private:
    char example[];
public:
    Game();
    bool PrintArray();

};

#endif /* GAME_H_ */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has three problems:

1) Array example in Game.h is a static array of zero length (so you can't add characters there) 
Solution: make a const pointer to an array of characters

2) Inside the Game's constructor you create a NEW variable example, do not affect the variable in the Game.h -> your variable in the class just don't updated
solution: `example = "PASS";`

3) In func Game::PrintArray you are printing only first character
Solution: `cout << example << endl;`

Game.h:

```
class Game {
private:
    const char* example;
public:
    Game();
    bool PrintArray();

};
```

Game.cpp:

```
Game::Game() {
    example = "PASS";
}

bool Game::PrintArray() {
    cout << example << endl;
    return true;
}
```

---

But even more correct solution is to use `std::string`. Then you don't have to worry about allocated/unallocated memory:

Game.h:

```
class Game {
private:
    std::string example;
public:
    Game();
    bool PrintArray();

};
```

Game.cpp:

```
Game::Game() {
    example = "PASS";
}

bool Game::PrintArray() {
    cout << example << endl;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're simply printing the first letter `P`. No memory allocation to hold the array as well.

Comment: This code may compile if your compiler is old and allows C++9X or C++03 stuff. In the new compiler you will get an error because `example = "PASS";` tries to write a `const char *` into `char *`, completely dropping the `const`.